# The apache2 configtest failed: Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: apache2, configuration

Everytime i restart apache2, the terminal output like this:

```
 * Restarting web server apache2                                         [fail] 
 * The apache2 configtest failed.
Output of config test was:
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: what is the output of `sudo tail /var/log/apache2/errors.log`

Answer (score 14):

I have successfully solved this problem by using this command: `sudo a2dismod php7.0` then i restart apache2, it work normally.

Comment: This is a workaround, not a solution. You should investigate further, especially if you need PHP.

Comment: Solved the problem ! Thanks mate, problems started after i installed some PHP module which was supposed to be for PHP 5.

Answer (score 5):

This happened for me after I upgraded MySQL from 5.5.55 to 5.7.x.  Not sure if it's related, but know from my experience that moving forward PHP to 7 and MySQL to 5.7 or greater and making everything play together nicely isn't always straightforward.

Anyway.. I did this:

```
a2dismod php7.0  //now it tells me to restart
service apache2 restart    //it worked!  But I want php7.0
//let's try and get it back
a2enmod php7.0   //oops, get this message: `ERROR: Module php5 is enabled - cannot proceed due to conflicts. It needs to be disabled first!`
a2dismod php5    //I don't need this for any of my sites
service apache2 restart
a2enmod php7.0   //it works with no errors indicated
service apache2 restart    //and, we're good to go!
```

Comment: I was trying to installing phpmyadmin and I get this error. I do the same steps of yours before reading your answer :P

Answer (score 5):

For me it helped to delete the

```
php5.conf
```

in `../mods-enabled/`
There were both `php7.conf` and `php5.conf` in `../mods-enabled/`.

I use php7.0 on Ubuntu 16 and php5.3 is installed with `phpbrew` but off...

Answer (score 2):

In my case the problem was upgrade of apache/php that added 2 symbolic links in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled:

```
php5.conf -> ../mods-available/php5.conf
php5.load -> ../mods-available/php5.load
```

Although I have now PHP 7.1, so removal of them fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a little late but depends on my situation it happened because two php versions was enabled. You can check enabled modules by `a2query -m` command and the disable the php version that you don't need. For example for me was php7.4: `sudo a2dismod php7.4`

Comment: after trying everything this answer saved my life.